# How to configure routes.rb to route any action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I'm tired of creating a new line in my routes.rb every time I add a new method in my controller. Is there a way in routes.rb to tell rails to accept any defined action in a given controller? I'm pretty sure I've done this before but can't remember how. I still need to explicitly specify the controller, however, because many other people use this routes file.

Thanks!

Comment: Is this little bit of convenience really worth losing the RESTful routing rails is build around?

Comment: i guess that depends on the perceived value of restful routing, which should vary from application to application.

Answer (score 2):

This is from the default generated `config/routes.rb` file

```
# This is a legacy wild controller route that's not recommended for RESTful applications.
# Note: This route will make all actions in every controller accessible via GET requests.
# match ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))'
```

Comment: hmm... i need to specify the controller explicitly. when i try to do that with the above format, rails complains that i didn't use ":controller".